# Unexpected AUTO_INCREMENT behaviour

Tags: codeigniter, auto-increment, mariadb

We have a server running PHP 5.6.7, mariadb 10.0.17-MariaDB.
We have a CodeIgniter application, in which we have two tables:
`point_trigger` and `trigger_filter`, which are connected with `point_trigger_id`, one-to-many. Both have an `id` column set to an integer with `AUTO_INCREMENT` (so no composite keys). This is what heppened:

1. A client removed one of the `point_trigger`s by a web interface. Sa basically called a controller that then removed the row from `point_trigger` and a row (just one in this case) from `trigger_filter`. The call was logged, it ends with `/delete/235`, meaning that `point_trigger_id` that was used to locate the rows to be deleted was set to `235`. So far so good.
2. Couple of days later client goes to the web interface again and adds a new `point_trigger`.
3. Client calls because the point trigger he created behaves unexpectedly.
4. We check the database, and... the `point_trigger` table does **NOT** have a gap in ids, meaning that the `point_trigger` that user created has **the same id** which is `235`. We check the associated `trigger_filter` table and this one also **doesn't have a gap**, the autoincremented id for this table is just the next one.

What we do know (or think that we know) is that both the **delete** and **add** went OK in terms of removing the rows. We think that because the `point_trigger` that client created after removing the previous one has different parameters, and *no edits were logged before the delete and the add*.

So apperantly there was something that made the AUTO_INCREMENT recalculate in the time between the delete and the add of `point_trigger`. Can anyone tell us or just point us to what it could be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: don't you say  `TRUNCATE TABLE` in any time interval?

Comment: Sorry for a delay - we do not truncate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> that user created has the same id which is 235

Could this be the sequence of events?

1. INSERT row and get 235 assigned
2. DELETE 235, leaving MAX(id)=234
3. Shut down MariaDB
4. Start up MariaDB
5. Insert row and get 235 again.

To elaborate on step 5:

- Open table -- find MAX(id)+1 (234+1) as the next id to assign for `AUTO_INCREMENT`
- INSERT now gets that value (235).

Sorry, but that is the way it works.  `AUTO_INCREMENT` guarantees uniqueness at any moment in time, not over all time.

Comment: Since we cannot figure out anything else for that time that passed, I'll assume that MariaDB had to be down and up and recalculate the `AUTO_INCREMENT` and mark this answer as good answer. Thank you for the explanation.